# Django Template Not Displaying Variables Correclty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a django page which is making an API call then displaying the results through a template. This has been working well but I must have changed something and now half the variables are not displaying correctly. Usually when there is an error calling a variable the template would just display a blank field. However, in my situation the webpage is displaying the code which is calling the variable. Here is what I have:

My HTML Code Looks like this:

```
<h6>Page</h6>
       <ul class="list-inline mx-auto row">
         <li class="list-group-item col-md-12">ASN: {{ context.upload.urlscan.page.asn }}</li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="list-inline mx-auto row">
         <li class="list-group-item col-md-12">ASN Name: {{ context.upload.urlscan.page.asnname }}</li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="list-inline mx-auto row">
         <li class="list-group-item col-md-12">IP: {{ context.upload.urlscan.page.ip }}</li>
       </ul>
```

From this code ONLY the first and third line are displaying correctly - These lines are displaying the variables that they are assigned to.

The middle value Labeled 'ASN Name' is displaying the code back. On the webpage it looks like this:

`{{ context.upload.urlscan.page.asnname }}`

I have verified that the data is coming in correctly and this is happening in several places in my code. Not sure why some variables are working and some are not.

I am using Django 2.1 and Python 3.6 on RHEL 7.x

**EDIT**
Per the request here is my context creation and render portion

```
    context['type'] = 'url'
    context['upload']['cs_response'] = cs_response
    context['upload']['cs_domain'] = cs_resp_dom
    context['upload']['ppdom_rep'] = ppdom_rep
    context['upload']['ppdom_ids'] = ppdom_ids
    context['upload']['cs_test'] = ioc
    context['upload']['urlscan'] = scan_res
    context['js'] = json.dumps(context, indent=4)

return render(request, 'iocs/upload.html', {'context': context})
```

Comment: Aren't you missing any open _and/or_ close brackets in your template `{{` or `}}`? Although you should get an error in this case.

Comment: @PedramParsian  That was my first thought and its why I chose this segment of code to post. I feel if I were missing a bracket than none should work, but in this segment the first and third work

Comment: The only explanation I can think of (based on what you show) is that `scan_res.page.asnname` value is actually the _literal_ string `"{{ context.upload.urlscan.page.asnname }}"`

Comment: It’s not. I have verified that the data is being passed to the template correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

So this was a pain but I finally figured it out. I wanted to style a `div` and I did it in a kinda lazy way. My django template was extended from a 'base' template so right under the `{% block content %}` tag I added a `<style>` tag.

This worked and styled the div correctly, however for some reason it broke half my variables on the page. I HAVE NO IDEA WHY! When debugging I commented this entire `<style>` block out and my code was still broken. I had to completely delete the `<style>` block for it to work again.

Once the `<style>` block was removed all variables began working...